# Displaying an icon on something that is not clickable

Tags: jquery-mobile

I was wondering if it is possible to display an icon on an element that is not <a> or <button>. Say a <p> or an <h2> element for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can.

[Demo JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BVA7X/2/)

```
<button class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-action">action</button>

<p class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-action">p</p>

<h2 class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-action">h2</h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to use the icons inline within the text of a `<p />` element for example, you can try this:

```
<span class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon nonbuttonicon" >
    <span class="ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline"></span>
</span>

.nonbuttonicon .ui-btn {
    cursor: default;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

By using spans, you can insert any number of icons in any position within the paragraph.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8LfY4/)**